# Prove that the induced matrix norm $||A||_{\infty}$ is equal to its maximum absolute row sum.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, numerical-methods

> Prove that the induced matrix norm $||A||_{\infty}$ is equal to its maximum absolute row sum.

This is my first time working through a proof in numerical analysis. Is my workings correct? If not, how do I solve this proof? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Suppose the maximum row is obtained from row $k$ of the matrix $A$. Then choose vector $x$ defined by $x_j = 1$ if $a_{kj} \geq 0$ and $x_j = -1$ if $a_{kj} < 0.$ Then $||x||_{\infty} = 1$ and

$$||A||_{\infty} \geq ||Ax||_{\infty} \geq \left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj}x_j \right|= \sum ^{n}_{j=1} |a_{kj}| = R$$.

Hence here we have a specific vector of length $1$ for which the vector norm $A$ dominates the maximum row sum. Hence,

$$||A||_{\infty} = R $$

Edit:

Let $||x||_{\infty} = 1$ then by the definition $|x_i| \leq 1 $ and $|x_k| =1$ for some $k$. Then

$$||Ax||_{\infty} =  max _{i}\left|\sum^n_{j=1}a_{ij}x_j \right| \leq max_{i}\sum^{n}_{j=1} |a_{ij}| = R$$

Hence the max row sum is always greater than or equal to the infinity vector norm of $A$

Comment: Provided that you showed first that $\|A\|_\infty\le R$, that proof is correct.

Comment: @LutzL thanks for the comment, I am not sure how to do this, could you show me how?

Comment: @LutzL I have an idea how to do this, could you check my edit to see if it correct? working on it now

Comment: Just apply the triangle inequality, $$\|Ax\|_∞=\max_k\left|\sum_ja_{kj}x_j\right|\le \max_k\sum_j\left|a_{kj}\right|\,\|x\|_∞.$$

Comment: @LutzL check my edit, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct and should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on another answer [you should have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165846/proof-for-infinity-matrix-norm)
$$ \| A\|_{\infty} = \max_{\| x\|_{\infty} =1} \| Ax\| = \max_{\| x\|_{\infty} =1} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|  \bigg\| \sum_{j=1}^{n}  a_{ij} x_{i} \bigg\|  \tag{1} $$

$$  \max_{\| x\|_{\infty} =1} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|  \bigg\| \sum_{j=1}^{n}  a_{ij} x_{i} \bigg\| = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}  \max_{ \| x\|_{\infty} = 1} \bigg\| \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij} x_{j}\bigg\|\tag{2} $$

$$  \max_{\| x\|_{\infty} =1} \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|  \bigg\| \sum_{j=1}^{n}  a_{ij} x_{i} \bigg\| = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}   \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|\tag{3} $$

$$  \| x\|_{1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}| \tag{4} $$

$$ \|A\|_{\infty} = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \| a_{i} \|_{1} \tag{5}  $$

Comment: @so which one is correct? 1 or 2? and is this in combination with my solution?

Comment: I don't see why you need $\max_{i} $  in front of your sum the $\ell_{\infty} $ norm is $\max_{1 \leq i \leq  m} | x_{i} |$   it is the max of the row already... where $a_{j}$ is a column

Comment: so could you edit a complete answer into yours? then I can accept, thanks btw!

Comment: thanks for your edit! is your edit a complete solution or do I need to include mine still?

Comment: @fr14 Do you need to yours? I just tried to figure this out now. I'm kind of unsure on the indexing. I was mostly confused where you put $R$  in the last step and I was clarifying in between steps. Unless you're using $R$ for $\max_{1\leq j\leq n} \| a_{j}^{*} \|_{1}$

Comment: I don't need to use mine I wasn't sure if it was correct

Comment: so then yours is a complete solution

Comment: I need to check for where I changed the max thing. you can do whatever you want. you were technically correct. I started typing before you put an edit.

Comment: so my edit I made was correct then? I was trying to get some confirmation. I am trying to read through and understand your solution now

Comment: The first line already is not helpful. You based your calculation on the columns of $A$ where it should have been the rows. In the end you should use $|A_jx|\le\|A_j\|_1\,\|x\|_\infty$, which I do not see in your answer.

Comment: I've edited it now and it makes more sense.

Comment: @RHowe so now your is complete and correct?

Comment: @fr14 I believe so

Comment: @RHowe thanks for your help!