# Infinity norm and operator norm question

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms

Suppose a matrix $A$ and a vector $v$ are given for appropriate size. In the Euclidean norm $\| \cdot \|_2$, we know that $$\|A v\|_2 \le \|A\|_{\text{op}} \cdot \|v\|_2$$ where $\|A\|_{\text{op}}$ is an operator norm of a matrix $A$. In a case of the infinity norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$, does the similar result hold? That is, is the following true? $$\|A v\|_\infty \le \|A\|_{\text{op}} \cdot \|v\|_\infty$$ If not, how can we bound $\|A v\|_\infty$?

Comment: It holds for any norm. In general, the operator norm in question will vary depending on the norm though. (That is, $\|A\|_{\text{op}}$ will be different values in your equations, since its value is relative to the norm on your vectors, but otherwise the inequality holds, essentially by definition.)

Comment: @PrincessEev I need to specify the operator norm that I want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2165846/339790)